# "This product is good value" vs "This product is of good value" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

1.This product **is good value**.
2.This product **is of good value**.

Are there any difference in meaning between "good value" and "of good value"?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. The difference is we never use a preposition in the construction *X is **good value***. I can't exactly say why the opposite applies with, say *It is **of** sound construction*. There are other related adjectival phrases where it's more a matter of stylistic choice (so *This product is of poor design* and *It is poor design* both seem "reasonable" to me).

Comment: "Never" is a long time, @FumbleFingers , and you know there are few with whom I would less rather contend, but [this enquoted phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+product+is+good+value.%22) search returns lots of counterexamples to your holding. _Somebody_ is using "X is good value," and they seem mostly to be NAmE speakers.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Perhaps you missed my point. Your link has many instances of *the product is good value* (with ***no*** preposition, as I said). Note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+good+value%2Cit+is+of+good+value&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20good%20value%3B%2Cc0), where the version *with* a preposition *(it is **of** good value)* doesn't occur often enough to chart. I'm a bit surprised that many AmE speakers seem to endorse *it is **a** good value* though - that doesn't sound good to my ear either.

Comment: There is a huge difference in meaning: of high quality goes to the category. The noun without of does not. 10—used as a function word to indicate a characteristic or distinctive quality or possession
a woman of courage

Answer (score 1):

"Of good value" doesn't seem quite right.  The phrase I'd use is "a good value" or just "good value", depending on the context.  "The spinach I get from the farmer's market is a good value," or, "You should buy the economy-size detergent -- it's (a) good value for the money."

You can say "of good value" but in a sentence like, "What do we mean when we speak of 'good value'?" However, a more natural sentence would be something like, "What do we mean if we say something is 'a good value'?"

Of course "of good value" might seem natural to other English-speakers, so out of context I'd say it means roughly the same thing as "a good value".

Answer (score 1):

“Good value,” “of good value,” and “a good value” are all equivalent in meaning. They all describe a given product’s quality as being notably high relative to its price.

To my native AmE ear, “of good value” sounds a bit formal and “good value” informal. Perhaps not surprisingly, I find “a good value” most natural, *e.g.*,

> At lunchtime, that restaurant is a great value: the food and service are both fantastic. The dinner menu, however, is a little pricier.