# "The car is high quality" VS. "The car is of high quality"

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference here? The word, of, is among the most difficult English word to learn, I guess...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This product is good value" vs "This product is of good value" in a sentence.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104874/this-product-is-good-value-vs-this-product-is-of-good-value-in-a-sentence) Also [“High quality” usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107925/high-quality-usage) (specifically asking whether it's *high quality*, or ***of** high quality*, same as you're asking here).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica There is a difference not explained by that other answer. And I just wrote it out: of high quality means: 10—used as a function word to indicate a characteristic or distinctive quality or possession
a woman of courage. This is not a duplicate!

Comment: @Lambie: The *question* is obviously a duplicate (of at least one, if not both of the ones I linked to). If you think there's a meaningful difference not covered by answers to either of those, *that's* were you should be setting it out, not here. Personally, I think the difference is simply one of *syntactic construction*, not *semantics* - but you're perfectly entitled to hold a different opinion on that score. Just not on the matter of whether it's a duplicate, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Those are different questions. of good value and of high quality. You were a little too fast on the trigger here. The difference is this: of x= a categoryof some kind. whereas x is just a noun. And that's a huge difference. There are now two reopen votes.

Comment: Like I said, a *syntactic* distinction, not a semantic one. Which is of no interest to me, but if you think it's important, *add an answer to one of the earlier questions*. There's no possible justification for having multiple questions that are all about exactly the same syntactic choice.